# How to parse single xml node in windows phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, xelement

```
<root>1234</root>
```

how do I pasrse this single xml node and it comes from web service response,
I am using:

```
void webservice_completedeventArgs()
{
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
}
```

this code runs very well in Emulator but in device when I debug, I am getting this error:

"Data at Root level is invalid"

I think its happening due to, There is no XML Dclaration in web service response like

```
"<XML Version 1.0 Encoding UTF-8?>"
```

So how do I parse that single XML node.
Please any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @JaiHind help me out brother...

Comment: What is `e.Result` here?

Comment: @TankorSmash see my edited code, e.Result is the web service response

Comment: please log and publish the content of e.Result

Comment: what is the difference between the response you receive in the emulator vs the device? You could set up some unit tests to try parsing out various formats of the result so you can see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @flo my e.Result is.... <root>1234</root>

Comment: @earthling i am getting the response in emulator nd response is....<root>1234</root> while in device i am getting error nd it is "DATA AT ROOT LEVEL IS INVALID"...please how to solve this..thanks

Comment: Please log the response you get on your device where you get this error. Not from the emulator!

Comment: I am getting this error on my device: "Data at Root level is invalid"...thanks!!

Comment: simply log/outupt the response as text. don't parse it yet

Comment: @flo I am using this code... string str = e.Result.ToString(),
but having the same problem...it runs in emulator but returns error in device.

Comment: Well, if this is the response... Does the Server returns this message: "DATA AT ROOT LEVEL IS INVALID"? what is the type of e.Result?

Comment: @flo in this web service response, it does not contain XML declaration, so i think windows device is taking the type of e.Result is String